# How can i install mysql workbench in fedora 11

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora

I download and try to install the rpm package for fedora 10, i also try compiled from source and finally ry to rebuild de rpm pakage from src.rpm package .. and nothing work.. does anyone know how can i install mysql workbench in fedora 11 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Belongs on server fault or fedora forums :)

Comment: You should post the error messages you have.  That is the path to enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2009/07/01/mysql-worbench-5.1.16-1-en

you can find the latest version of mysql-workbench for fedora 11 here!

Answer (score 0):

Get the RPM package and try this:

```
yum localinstall mysql-workbench-whatever.rpm
```

Maybe it's a dependency problem. If that's the case, the above command will pick up whatever other packages are needed (if they're available in the Fedora repositories).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench discussions:   http://forums.mysql.com/index.php?151

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this page : http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2009/07/01/mysql-worbench-5.1.16-1

```
- wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/remi-release-11.rpm
- rpm -Uvh remi-release-11.rpm
- yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql-workbench
```